# How to protect ajax from being used without login?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, django, linux

If I have a website with login and session management, and the pages uses ajax to send form data to the server side.

How do I protect anyone from just saving the HTML and JavaScripts, and thereby completely bypassing the login and session management?

Do you generate a token on successful login, and send this along with the JSON string, so the server side script can check against this?

If so, does there exist solutions for this that I can just use, so I don't have to write them myself?

I am interested in both Djando and ROR solutions, as I am trying out both right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement logging in on the server. AJAX requests exist within the same session as regular request, so if someone is logged in, they are logged in for the AJAX request too. If the user is not logged in, you can check this for the AJAX request too. Check on the server if a user is logged in and return an error code if not.

The server should never rely on the client to tell it whether someone is logged in. The only client data to use for that is the session token, combined with the IP address if you want to be more secure.

Comment: I would add; if the login/session is not over HTTPS it should never be considered secure, hashed with an IP or not.

Comment: Yes, that's true, although without the IP, one could just copy the session cookie to any machine to take over the session. But indeed, you need SSL if you want to be safe.

Comment: @Chris Farmiloe : Why is SSL important in this case?

Comment: @GolezTrol : When you say "AJAX requests exist within the same session as regular request". Is that in Django or ROR?

Comment: Either, I think. Afaik, all major server platforms use a session cookie to identify the session. HTTP is stateless, but by storing a unique session id in a cookie, you can link each request to a specific session. These cookies are sent with AJAX requests too, so the server doesn't even know whether it is an AJAX request. It is just another request in the same session.

Comment: @GolezTrol : I see. Does it have to cookies? Could I use session ID in the URL instead, to avoid that my website requires cookie enabled browser?

Comment: @Sandra, I was just expanding on Golez's note about securing sessions. The method he mentioned is a common way to avoid an easy session hijack, but I just wanted to note that it shouldn't be considered "secure". RE: cookies, if you are using AJAX I think it's safe to assume all your clients have modern browsers with decent cookie support :)

Comment: If you store the session id in the url, that also means that the session id is stored in the browser history, and that the user may accidentally copy the url to someone else, thus making the reciever unwilling steal the user's session. It is uncommon to use other methods than cookies.

Answer (score 2):

You create a token and save it on the cookie. Then check for that cookie every where. Including all your ajax pages. The cookies will also be sent when you do ajax request. This is the only secured option I can think. You always have to check for the token in the backend and reject if not authorized.

Comment: Is a cookie required? I would prefer to use add a session ID to each URL, so I don't depend on the client allowing cookies. Would that be just as good?

Comment: Normally you would use a cookie, but otherwise, you can keep the session ID somewhere else in the client-side. If you need to transfer to another page, you can pass it in the query-string (if this is acceptable).

Answer (score 0):

Use a server side session cookie
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Answer (score 0):

Add a before_filter to your application controller that validates the user is logged in:

before_filter :login_required

def login_required
  unless current_user
     redirect to login page
end